# TS React: buildArray is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Minimizing my current issue, I have this:

```
// inside a functional component
  const buildArray: any = ["1", "2"].map((value: string, index) => {   
    return (
      <li key={`${value}`}>{value}</li>
    )
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledTopNav>
        {buildArray()}
      </StyledTopNav>
    </div>
  )
```

```
TypeError: buildArray is not a function
push../src/components/TopNav.tsx.__webpack_exports__.default
src/components/TopNav.tsx:42
  39 | 
  40 | return (
  41 |   <div>
> 42 |     <StyledTopNav>
     | ^  43 |       {buildArray()}
  44 |     </StyledTopNav>
  45 |   </div>
```

[image: error in browser]

Anyone know the issue? when I had written `li` elements directly inside the styled `ul` JSX component, it all worked (but there was code duplication between `li`'s. I'm copying the styled `ul` below just in case.

```
const StyledTopNav = styled.ul`
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px dashed orange;
`;
```

Comment: As the message tells you, it's *not* a function; you can't call it. It's an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the declaration of `buildArray`, you can use the following code to declare it as a function:

```js
const buildArray = () => {
  return [0, 1, 2, 3].map(i => {
    return (
      <div>
        {i}
        </div>
    )
  })
}
```